# Imprimir valores de un crud en un select con php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, bootstrap

espero no les pese mucho echarme una mano con esto, la cuestión es que estoy creando un crud bastante sencillo en php, como es el siguiente.

**index.php**
[image: crud en php]
Y estas son las columnas en el phpmyadmin

[image: tabla "alumnos"]

**crear.php**
[image: creando alumno]

Quisiera que lo que se pone en ese formulario, en la parte de "rol" aparezca también reflejado en un select para un formulario de registro en la página.

Es decir, quiero que a la hora de rellenar el formulario tal que así (por ejemplo)...

[image: registro]

Lo que se ponga específicamente en "Rol" también aparezca en un  dentro de un  de otro formulario de registro, así los usuarios puedan elegir registrarse con ese rol creado por otros usuarios.

Este es el código del formulario **crear.php** que enviará la información.

```
<?php
include 'funciones.php';

csrf();
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) {
  die();
}

$error = false;
$config = include 'config.php';

try {
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['name'];
  $conexion = new PDO($dsn, $config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass'], $config['db']['options']);

  if (isset($_POST['rol'])) {
    $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE rol LIKE '%" . $_POST['rol'] . "%'";
  } else {
    $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM alumnos";
  }

  $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($consultaSQL);
  $sentencia->execute();

  $alumnos = $sentencia->fetchAll();

} catch(PDOException $error) {
  $error= $error->getMessage();
}

$titulo = isset($_POST['rol']) ? 'Lista de alumnos (' . $_POST['rol'] . ')' : 'Lista de alumnos';
?>

<?php include "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php
if ($error) {
  ?>
  <div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <?= $error ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <a href="crear.php"  class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Crear alumno</a>
      <hr>
      <form method="post" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mr-3">
          <input type="text" id="rol" name="rol" placeholder="Buscar por rol" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escapar($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ver resultados</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="mt-3"><?= $titulo ?></h2>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Rol</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Edad</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
          if ($alumnos && $sentencia->rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach ($alumnos as $fila) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo escapar($fila["id"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escapar($fila["nombre"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escapar($fila["rol"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escapar($fila["email"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escapar($fila["edad"]); ?></td>
                <td>
                  <a href="<?= 'borrar.php?id=' . escapar($fila["id"]) ?>">️Borrar</a>
                  <a href="<?= 'editar.php?id=' . escapar($fila["id"]) ?>">✏️Editar</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
            }
          }
          ?>
        <tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php include "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Gracias por su atención y ayuda :3

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Tienes una tabla donde está todos los roles? Si es así, entonces, cuando crees el formulario, pon un `select option` el cual llenarás consultando a la tabla `rol` o como se llame.

Comment: Exacto y quiero que ese ese select option con los roles se muestre en un campo de registro de usuario, es decir que un usuario al registrarse, pueda elegir un rol, ¿Vale?

Comment: Perfecto. Pero mi pregunta es: ¿ya tienes una tabla donde almacenas los roles? ¿Cómo se llama esa tabla? Se trataría de tener una tabla con dos columnas: `rolID` y `rol` y luego en `alumnos` poner una columna numérica que haga la relación con `rolID` en la tabla `rol`.

Comment: Correcto, tengo una tabla con esas dos columnas, supongo que con "columna numérica" te refieras a crear una columna de tipo entero, pero, ¿Cómo hago la relación exactamente?

Comment: La relación se hace en los `CREATE TABLE` o se añaden a posteriori con `ALTER TABLE`, pero para eso, las tablas deben estar en el engine `InnoDB`, luego, en las consultas, si quieres obtener el texto del rol, debes hacer un `JOIN` entre `alumnos` y `rol`, pues queda claro que en `alumnos` guardarás el valor numérico, no el texto. Si no entiendes algunos de los conceptos de los que te estoy hablando, paciencia, porque son varias cosas que supongo irás aprendiendo con el tiempo, pues es un tema amplio, pero muy importante si quieres diseñar bien tu modelo de datos.

Comment: Pues entiendo que la instrucción CREATE TABLE sirve para empezar a crear una tabla y con ALTER TABLE se modifica una tabla con lo del SQL, lo que no me queda claro es lo del JOIN, que supongo que nada de eso sería complicado.

Comment: Es correcto. En cuanto al `JOIN`, sería para cuando quieras presentar los datos del `alumno` y el rol como texto. Dado que en `alumnos` sólo tendrás el ID del rol, tendrías que hacer un `JOIN` entre las dos tablas para obtener el texto. Es así como se suele hacer en casos más comunes como ciudades por ejemplo, en la tabla `ciudad` estarían los id y los nombres de la ciudad y en la tabla que se relaciona con `ciudad` sólo guardas el ID de la ciudad, no el nombre de la misma.

Comment: Tengo una última duda ya que no te quiero quitar mucho tiempo. Mi idea con esto era que esos datos insertados a través de un formulario aparecieran impresos en un select option como originalmente pedí y que un usuario al registrarse, tenga esos datos. En este caso, supongamos que en la tabla rol tengo un registro de un rol que se llama "Médico", este rol de médico aparecerá como opción de un rol a elegir a la hora de registrarse en la página, ¿Cómo haría un echo en php ahí?

Espero que se entienda y gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con: *¿Cómo haría un echo en php ahí?* Simplemente, cuando creas el formulario, vas a llenar un `select option` leyendo los datos que hay en la tabla `rol`, y en cada `option` el `value` será el ID del rol (valor numérico) que se guardará en la tabla relacionada. Luego, cuando necesites presentar los datos, harás un `JOIN`, para traer el valor en texto del rol. Supongamos que en la tabla `rol` el ID del médico es `5`, pues en `alumnos` vas a guardar el valor `5` y luego haciendo el `JOIN` donde tengas que presentar todos los datos, extraerás por ese valor el ...

Comment: ... nombre del `rol`. Supongamos que en  la tabla `alumnos` tienes una columna que se llama `rolFK` y ella se relaciona con la columna `rolID` en la tabla `rol`, pues harás una consulta así más o menos cuando debas presentar los datos: `SELECT a.nombre, r.rol FROM alumnos AS a INNER JOIN rol AS r ON a.rolFK =  r.rolID`, si observas, en el `SELECT` puedes extraer datos tanto de la tabla `alumnos`, como de la tabla `rol`, gracias a que hay una columna por la que ambas tablas se relacionan.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas en este caso es normalizar, creando una nueva tabla `rol` que tendrá esta estructura más o menos:

```
rolID INT(11) PRIMARY KEY
rol   VARCHAR(150)
```

En cuanto a `alumnos`, en vez de definir una columna `rol` del tipo `VARCHAR` defines una columna numérica, la llamaremos `rolFK`. FK es una convención de nombrado que significa llave foránea y que puede ser útil para saber que a primera vista esa columna es llave foránea o extranjera en otra tabla. Luego, debes definir esas relaciones, sea en el `CREATE TABLE`, sea con `ALTER TABLE`, pero no nos metamos con eso, que es otro tema algo amplio, pero que deberías investigar y profundizar.

Entonces, en `alumno` tendremos esta columna:

```
rolFK INT(11)
```

Pasemos ahora el código PHP. Allí donde llenarás los datos de alumno, debes crear un `select  option` así:

```
$html="<select name=\"rol\">";
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT rolID, rol FROM rol ORDER BY rol");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $html .= sprintf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>"),$row['rolID'],$row['rol']);
}
$html .= "</select>";
echo $html;
```

Esto, entre otras cosas (los demás elementos del formulario) te creará un `select option` así más o menos:

```
<select name="rol">
  <option value="1">Abogado</option>
  <option value="2">Albañil</option>
  <option value="3">Dentista</option>
  <option value="4">Ingeniero</option>
  <option value="5">Médico</option>
</select>
```

Y, OJO, en `alumnos` se guardará el valor numérico del rol seleccionado, por ejemplo, para el caso de médico, se guardará el valor `5` **en la columna `rolFK` de la tabla `alumnos`**.

Luego, **allí donde necesites presentar los datos de un alumno o varios alumnos determinados**, harás un `JOIN` que será más o menos así:

```
SELECT 
    a.nombre, 
    a.tipo,
    r.rol 
FROM alumnos AS a 
    INNER JOIN rol AS r ON a.rolFK =  r.rolID
```

Si observas, estamos extrayendo el valor tipo cadena (VARCHAR) del rol (Médico u otro) usando la tabla `rol`, pero ese valor no existe en `alumnos`, lo que hemos puesto en `alumnos` es una referencia a ese valor por su id, usando la columna `rolFK`.

Es así como funciona más o menos. Pero te recomiendo que leas sobre bases de datos relacionadas, sobre llaves foráneas, sobre restricciones de integridad referencial, sobre selects dependientes, etc, porque es un tema muy amplio para explicarlo todo aquí.

Espero que esto te encamine y cualquier duda puedes preguntar comentando en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

no etoy seguro pero lo que entiendo es que nesecitas un select, no?
pero como lo dices mmm..... podrias crear una tabla aparte para tus roles de esa manera solo llamarias a esa tabla

```
    <div class="form-group mr-3">
              <select id="rol" name="rol" placeholder="Buscar por rol" class="form-control">
<?php
          if ($roles && $sentencia->rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach ($roles as $rol) {
              ?>
             <option  value="<?php echo escapar($rol["rol"]); ?>"><?php echo escapar($rol["rol"]); ?></option>
              <?php
            }
          }
          ?>
</select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tienes razón, puedo crear una tabla aparte de roles, no hay ningún problema, pero la cuestión es que quisiera que los registros de esa tabla aparecieran reflejados en un select option y que un usuario al registrarse, pueda elegir su "rol" con ese select option, ¿Cómo haría eso?

Comment: Recuerda que la sección de respuestas es para respuestas _completas_ a la pregunta. Procura no responder cuando aún no tienes detalles suficientes del problema en cuestión. Lee [answer].

Comment: Aparte de ser una respuesta parcial, como bien apunta @padaleiana, estás fomentando malas prácticas. [El Manual de PHP es claro cuando habla de `rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) al decir **que no se debe confiar en él para saber el número de filas que arroja una consulta del tipo `SELECT`**. Por tanto, la forma que usas para saber si hay filas no es la adecuada. Antes de aprender de tutoriales (en PHP abundan tutoriales muy antiguos, con pésimas prácticas) revisa la documentación oficial y luego intenta aprender de fuentes que implementen buenas prácticas.