# Select option dinámico a partir de formulario en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, bootstrap

esto es aparentemente fácil, pero como nunca lo he hecho, vengo a pedir ayuda primero.

Tengo un select option usando PHP que recibe la información únicamente desde la base de datos (ignoren las listas de la derecha, son solo para rellenar):

[image: select option]
[image: select option 2]

**Estructura DB**
[image: base de datos]

Aquí está el código.

**index.php**

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Select HTML con PHP y MySQL</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="container mt-5" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-5 mb-5">
        <h1 class="text-center" style="font-weight: 800;">Select HTML con PHP y MySQL</h1>
      </div>

      <?php
        $usuario  = "root";
        $password = "";
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $basededatos = "roles";
        $con = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die("No se ha podido conectar al Servidor");
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con, $basededatos) or die("Upps! Error en conectar a la Base de Datos");
        
        $sqlClientes         = ("SELECT * FROM  rol ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
        $dataClientesSelect  = mysqli_query($con, $sqlClientes);

        $dataClientes_ol       = mysqli_query($con, $sqlClientes); //Lista ordenada
        $dataClientes_ul       = mysqli_query($con, $sqlClientes); //lista desordenada
        $dataClientes_radio    = mysqli_query($con, $sqlClientes); //inputs tipo radio
        $dataClientes_checkbox = mysqli_query($con, $sqlClientes); //inputs tipo checkbox
      ?>

      
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
      <form action="">
      <label for="clientes" class="text-right">Lista de roles</label>
      <select name="rol" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option value="">Seleccione el rol</option>
        <?php
          while ($dataSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($dataClientesSelect)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $dataSelect["id"]; ?>">
              <?php echo utf8_encode($dataSelect["rol"]); ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Enviar rol</button>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
      <ol>
      <?php
        while ($dataOL = mysqli_fetch_array($dataClientes_ol)) { ?>
        <li><?php echo utf8_encode($dataOL["rol"]); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
      <ul>
      <?php
        while ($dataUL = mysqli_fetch_array($dataClientes_ul)) { ?>
        <li><?php echo utf8_encode($dataUL["rol"]); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>



    <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
      <?php
        while ($dataRadio = mysqli_fetch_array($dataClientes_radio)) { ?>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rol" id="<?php echo ($dataRadio["id"]); ?>" value="<?php echo ($dataRadio["id"]); ?>">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="rol">
          <?php echo utf8_encode($dataRadio["rol"]); ?>
          </label>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
      <?php
        while ($dataCheckbox = mysqli_fetch_array($dataClientes_checkbox)) { ?>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="rol" value="<?php echo $dataCheckbox["id"]; ?>" id="<?php echo $dataCheckbox["id"]; ?>">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $dataCheckbox["id"]; ?>">
            <?php echo utf8_encode($dataCheckbox["rol"]); ?>
          </label>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php




    ?>


  </div>
  </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Para insertar nuevos datos, sólo debo hacerlo manualmente desde la base de datos, entonces mi pregunta es:
¿Cómo creo un formulario para que inserte en "Lista de roles" un nuevo rol? (algo así como si fuera un CRUD).

Mi objetivo es que un usuario pueda registrarse usando ese rol creado, es decir crear otro formulario de **registro** donde ellos puedan elegir ese rol. *Vamos, el típico formulario de registro con usuario y contraseña, pero con el select option de antes*.

(algo así se vería)
[image: register.php]

He pensado en que el **id** de la tabla **roles** se le pueda asociar al usuario registrado, pero la verdad esto en la práctica me tiene bloqueado porque no manejo mucho sql, así que su ayuda significa mucho para mí. Espero esté bien explicado, gracias. :)

Comment: En la tabla `usuario` debes crear una columna numérica que guarde el ID del rol que sea seleccionado. Justamente ayer [expliqué eso con detalle en otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/564198/29967). ¿Hubo que no entendiste en mi respuesta?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es poder, desde ese formulario, insertar nuevos roles, entonces puedes poner un `option` que sea `Agregar nuevo Rol`, digamos con `value="-1"` y ahí puedes usar Ajax o la API Fetch de Javascript para pedir el valor, insertarlo en la BD y actualizar el `select option` sin moverte de la página. Para ello tendrás que escuchar por Javascript los cambios del `select option` y cuando el valor sea `-1` lanzar el proceso de inserción de un nuevo elemento. Es una forma de hacerlo, puede que haya otras ...

Comment: Sí leí tu respuesta y te lo agradezco mucho, pero creo que realmente no fui muy explícito con mi pregunta, así que decidí crear otro proyecto aparte para organizar mejor mi nueva pregunta. Esto es otra pregunta aparte de la de ayer, pero con el mismo enfoque.

Comment: Sí, leyendo más detenidamente esta nueva pregunta interpreto que querrías poder insertar nuevos roles, en caso de que no existan. Lo mejor en este caso sería poder hacerlo usando herramientas como Ajax o Fetch, que te van a permitir poder modificar los datos en el servidor de forma transparente y sin necesidad de recargar la página. Puedes por ejemplo pedir el dato en un `prompt`, hacer la inserción y luego actualizar el `select option` y poder usar ese nuevo valor sin moverte de la página.

Comment: En caso de que existan y en caso de que no existan también, pero el punto es que estos sean insertados a través de un formulario (para evitar insertarlos manualmente desde la base de datos) para ser usados como opción en la página de registro (como se ve en la última imagen).

Comment: En caso de que existan no, pues los que existan se mostrarán ya listados. Creo que no entendiste del todo la respuesta antes referida.

Comment: Sí, creo que leí mal, porque ahí ya se están imprimiendo. Pero igual, el objetivo es ese, que los usuarios creen roles y otros los puedan usar en su registro, creo que se entiende aunque me complico a veces explicando.

Comment: Ya te expliqué una forma posible para que los usuarios creen roles, ahora toca implementarla. Aunque Ajax o Fetch te suenen a chino, no es tan complicado y será más fácil que hacerlo de otro modo.

Comment: Intentaré el método AJAX ya que sí lo familiarizo más, espero no fallar intentándolo. ¿Puedo consultarte por aquí por los comentarios cualquier cosita o por otro medio?

Comment: No hay ningún problema, puedes consultar por aquí, abrir nuevas preguntas ante problemas nuevos, etc. Además, podrás tener el punto de vista de otros usuarios con igual o más conocimiento que yo según en qué lenguaje estés trabajando.